# partial extraction of urls due to bad handling of accented and punctuation characters

Tags: regex, powershell

Inside `film_disponibili.txt` I have these lines

```
La forza dell'amore
La forza della volontà
La fuga - Girl in Flight
```

Inside `html_di_test.txt` I have this html code

```
<a href="https://cb01.clinic/la-forza-dellamore-b-n-1936/">La forza dell&#8217;amore [B/N] (1936)</a>
<a href="https://cb01.clinic/la-forza-della-volonta-hd-1988/">La forza della volontà [HD] (1988)</a>
<a href="https://cb01.clinic/la-fuga-girl-in-flight-hd-2016/">La fuga &#8211; Girl in Flight [HD] (2016)</a>
<a href="https://cb01.clinic/lo-studente-1982/">Lo studente (1982)</a>
```

I try to writes into a file called `urls_estratti.txt` only these urls extracted from `html_di_test.txt`

```
https://cb01.clinic/la-forza-dellamore-b-n-1936/
https://cb01.clinic/la-forza-della-volonta-hd-1988/
https://cb01.clinic/la-fuga-girl-in-flight-hd-2016/
```

but I get only this url

```
https://cb01.clinic/la-forza-della-volonta-hd-1988/
```

these urls are missing and I don't understand why

```
https://cb01.clinic/la-forza-dellamore-b-n-1936/
https://cb01.clinic/la-fuga-girl-in-flight-hd-2016/
```

This is the code that I'm trying to set

```
    $films = Get-Content .\film_disponibili.txt
$html = Get-Content .\html_di_test.txt -Raw

$urls = foreach ($film in $films) {
    $film_decoded = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($film)
    $regex = '.*<a href="(https://cb01.clinic/.*)">' + [regex]::Escape($film_decoded) + '.*'
    $match = [regex]::Match($html, $regex)
    if ($match.Success) { $match.Groups[1].Value }
}

$urls | Set-Content .\urls_estratti.txt
```

Condition is this: if there is a string like `La fuga - Girl in Flight` into

```
 <a href="https://cb01.clinic/la-fuga-girl-in-flight-hd-2016/">La fuga &#8211; Girl in Flight [HD] (2016)</a> `
```

script should be write this url: `https://cb01.clinic/la-fuga-girl-in-flight-hd-2016/`

But this doesn't totally happen, I saw that there is a problem with the accented characters, the apostrophe and the dash in the middle of the name, but I can't handle them completely

Comment: Why are you using regex to parse html? This would be as simple as `$html.getElementsByTagName('a') | ForEach-Object href` using `htmlfile` to extract those urls

Comment: `&#8217;` is a smart quote and `&#8211;` is a En dash which don't match `'` or `-` respectively hence your problem

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon ah... I hate these kind of problems..mm.. now I see, so `$html = $html.Replace("&#8217;", "'")` and `$html = $html.Replace("&#8211;", "-")` solve

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comments `&#8217;` is a smart quote and `&#8211;` is a en dash which don't match `'` or `-` respectively hence your problem.

You could change your `film_disponibili.txt` file to the following:

```
La forza dell\p{P}amore
La forza della volontà
La fuga \p{P} Girl in Flight
```

Using `\p{P}` you can match any kind of punctuation character.

Then another take on solving this problem is using `Htmlfile` to parse `html_di_test.txt`.

Code would look as follows:

```bash
$toMatch = Get-Content .\film_disponibili.txt
$content = Get-Content .\html_di_test.txt -Raw

$html = New-Object -ComObject htmlfile
$html.write([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($content))

$predicate = [Func[object, bool]]{ $_.textContent -match $args[0] }
$html.getElementsByTagName('a') |
    Where-Object { [Linq.Enumerable]::Any($toMatch, $predicate) } |
    ForEach-Object href
```

And output would be:

```
https://cb01.clinic/la-forza-dellamore-b-n-1936/
https://cb01.clinic/la-forza-della-volonta-hd-1988/
https://cb01.clinic/la-fuga-girl-in-flight-hd-2016/
```